# Stringify keys error if change page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application that uses javascript to make a quiz game on the first page. However, if after playing the game or during the game a user clicks on any links (unassociated with the game) on the home page that redirect to another page (for example, a link to a profile page) then I get an error

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for "Quiz question..?":String
```

in the show action of the users controller (for example if they clicked a profile link)

Also, once the error's triggered, it's very hard to restore the application. I think the string causing the error's getting cached...

Is there a way to prevent that error from getting raised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that I was using the same session variable in two different situations. On the home page, I created a `session[:question]` to store questions for the quiz. However, on the profile page, I also allow users to create questions and was storing them in `session[:question].' Therefore, when I moved from the homepage to the user profile page, certain logic was triggered that created the error. However, renaming one of the session[:question] to session[:userquestion] fixed the problem.